# Laravel Route::delete NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

The DELETE request on one of my forms throws a `NotFoundHttpException`

The route:

```
itemsTypes = [ 'foo', 'bar' ]
Route::delete('{type}/{id}/delete', 'ItemTaxonomyController@destroy')
    ->where('type', $itemsTypes);
```

The form which uses it:

```
{!! Form::open( [action('ItemTaxonomyController@destroy', [$type, $item->item_id]), 'delete']) !!}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're opening your form incorrectly. Replace

```
{!! Form::open( [action('ItemTaxonomyController@destroy', [$type, $item->item_id]), 'delete']) !!}
```

with

```
{!! Form::open( [ 'url' => action('ItemTaxonomyController@destroy', [$type, $item->item_id]), 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
```